# Is it possible to add a sql DB to sharepoint site?

Tags: 2013

Can we add a sql db to the sharepoint(2013) site or library without BCS? if yes, how do i do that.

could anyone let me know the detail steps about how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

With the External Content Types feature provided in SharePoint 2013, communication between two systems can be achieved easily. By using SQL Server as Data Source, you can minimize writing explicit code for database connectivity and perform CRUD operations too.

[SharePoint List From SQL Server Table (External Content Type with SharePoint Designer)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mind_talks/archive/2012/04/03/sharepoint-list-from-sql-server-table-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer.aspx)

[Configuring SharePoint 2013 ECT & BCS for SQL Connectivity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianragusa/archive/2014/07/19/configuring-sharepoint-2013-ect-amp-bcs-for-sql-connectivity.aspx)